# Select from enum in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, filter, enums

I have an enum `Colors(RED=0, BLACK=1, BLUE=2, WHITE=3, PINK=4)`. I want to get a list of colors corresponding to the values in a list. For example, if the list is `[1, 3, 4]`, I want to get a filtered list such as `[BLACK=1, WHITE=3, PINK=4]`. I tried searching through the documentation but couldn't find any function which does that. Is it possible?

Comment: What implementation of enums are you using? enum.Enum? What documentation did you read exactly? Provide links and quotes for the parts that might be useful

Comment: So from a list like `[1, 3, 4]` you want to get `[BLACK, WHITE, PINK]` right ?

Comment: Well, maybe a tuple like [(BLACK,1), (WHITE,3), (PINK,4)]

Comment: @MadPhysicist Went through this: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/enum.html

Comment: Your initialization is wrong BTW. @obgnaw's answer shows the correct way to initialize an enum.

Answer (score 1):

```
from enum import Enum
class Color(Enum):
    RED = 1
    GREEN = 2
    BLUE = 3
    PINK = 4

indexes  = [1, 3, 4]
for i in indexes:
    print((Color(i).name,i))
```

**N.B.** A `ValueError` will be raised if the `indexes` list has an invalid int.

Comment: I get TypeError: object() takes no parameters.

Comment: @obgnaw. Where do you get a ValueError?

Comment: you may check your code.this came from[link](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/enum.html#programmatic-access-to-enumeration-members-and-their-attributes)

Comment: when you pass some value where the enum don't have,then it will raise a value error,it's the design.but i think i should say it before.in my example,`Color(5)`will.@MadPhysicist

Answer (score 0):

To transform a list of `int`s to a matching list of `Enum` members:

```
new_list = [Color(i) for i in old_list]
```